# Would calling statvfs / statfs periodically cause wear on disk?

Tags: macos, posix

I'm having an app that shows the current free disk space and that finds this out via calls to statfs on macOS. Does anyone have an insight in the implementation of statfs how this might affect the disk if I call this function periodically? Assuming it will be similar on Linux and other posix system with statvfs.

Comment: This is implementation dependent, but I suppose that on many systems values are cached in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX doesn't require that any timestamps or counters are updated for a `statvfs` call, so there is no quasi-mandatory overhead.

However, periodic polling could still affect battery life and consume network bandwidth (for network file systems).